# Func for async goes in deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, func, stackexchange.redis

**Objective:**

I am using redis for cache and trying to get a cache value if not available get from repo and set the cache value.

**Problem:**

client side js keeps waiting forever and it seems to be in some type of deadlock

**Code causing issue**

```
   return await _cacheStore.GetAsync("CacheKey", new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0),
                 async () =>
                  await _repo.GetAllAsync()
                  );
```

**Code that works, but kinda redundant as i keep using this pattern a lot of places.**

```
    var data = await _cacheStore.GetAsync<List<objectType>>("cacheKey");
    if (data == null)
    {
        data = await _repo.GetAllAsync();
        _cacheStore.SetAsync<List<objectType>>("cacheKey", data, new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
    }
    return data;
```

//Possible Problem function below passing async method as Func?????
**Functions called by above code**

```
public static async Task < T > GetAsync < T > (this IRedisCacheStore source, string key, TimeSpan time, Func < Task < T >> fetch) where T: class {
 if (source.Exists(key)) {
  return await source.GetAsync < T > (key);
 } else {
  var result = fetch();

  if (result != null) {
   source.Set(key, result, time);
  }

  return await result;
 }
}

public async Task < List < ObjectType >> GetAllAsync() {
 var result = await _procExecutor.ExecuteProcAsync < ObjectType > ("Sproc", null);

 return (result ? ? new List < ObjectType > ()).ToList();
}

public async Task < IEnumerable < TResult >> ExecuteProcAsync < TResult > (string sproc, object param) {
  using(var conn = _connection.GetConnection()) {
   return await conn.QueryAsync < TResult > (sproc, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
  }
```

Here is my redis cacheStore

```
public interface IRedisCacheStore
{
    bool Exists(string key);
    T Get<T>(string key);
    void Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiredIn);
    void Remove(string key);

    Task<bool> ExistsAsync(string key);
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key);
    Task SetAsync<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiredIn);
    Task RemoveAsync(string key);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an async delegate at all? Why not simply `() => _repo.GetAllAsync()` ? Or even just `_repo.GetAllAsync` ?

Comment: i tried that way as well and it produced same result so i tried with async () => await and it had same result as well. client js showed pending and when i debug it just continues and does not break anywhere and seems likes its done processing all code request

Comment: Except, as already said, you don't need async delegate at all, also here: var result = fetch(); - this should be var result = await fetch();. You then store variable of type Task<T> in redis cache (via Set), who knows what that does.

Comment: The most common cause of deadlocks with `async` is if you're synchrnonously waiting on `async` code. Do you do that? Could you show the code the calls the methods you showed here? Ideally, provide a [mcve].

Comment: i should have added await in var result = fetch();

Comment: Dose this happen when you make a single request or multiple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var result = fetch();

if (result != null) {
   source.Set(key, result, time);
}
```

`fetch()` returns `Task<T>`, and that is what you are trying to store in Redis cache and Task is (obviously) not serializable. Just use:

```
var result = await fetch();
```